# ksql query array of structs by value in the struct

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I have an array of structs. The array is an output of delta processing, thats why the count of structs differ (and the struct B sometimes have the position 1, but also can have the position 5).
A struct in the array looks like this:
{
val:{
asString:"12345"
},
position:"1200"
}

Another Example:

{
val:{
asString:"12927"
},
position:"1120"
}

I want to query the Value as String by using the position-key. I know which position keys to query, but i dont know how to get the value, because the position-Value is part of the struct.
The whole object has a key to identify a object

I thought of exploding the array and create a new event with the object identifying key.
The object itself has about 6000 lines, which would return a huge amount of events (which i am trying to avoid).
Maybe an switch to kafka streams is necessary?

Comment: You can use `->` notation to access STRUCT fields... But yes, you need to explode an ARRAY first. What have you tried? What exactly do you mean by "by key"?

Comment: As it is an array of structs you cannot access the structs by -> (because you don't know the position in the array). Exploding the array is an option, but way to complex and not a really good solution. By key I meant, that I wanted to access specific structs by the position attribute in the struct

Answer (score 1):

I found a good working solution:
In my case I knew which keys (or position-attributes in the structs) I was searching for.
Therefore you can use the FILTER Method of Arrays to filter the struct, which has the specific value in the position-attribute, i was searching for.
You can do this for all the values you are searching for (if the position key is missing, you just get a null value, but in my case that was totally alright)
That's a good way to implement it in ksql without using Kafka Streams.
(FYI I am trying to avoid Kafka Streams, because it is not a confluent cloud nativ product and requires deeper java knowledge)